# count webelements from page in protractor

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

How to get count elements on the page? I have:

```
public countElements(){
    element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count().then(function(count) {
        console.log(count);
      });
      return count; // cannot find element count
}
```

I know that count is invisibility outside but how to do count to be visible?
How to return variable count in method countElements() ?

Comment: I would guess you need to declare that variable outside that function?

Comment: I tried but always get undefined

Answer (score 2):

```
public countElements(){
    return element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps')).count();
}
```

And then in the test:

```
page.countElements().then(count => {
    console.log(count);

    expect(count).toBe(myCount);
});
```

To use `count` in other methods you may want to use `async/await`.

```
let count = await page.countElements();
myOtherMethod(count);
```

Or you could implement your own promise and resolve it. Something like this should do the trick.

```
public countElements(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        element.all(by.repeater('app in userApps'))
          .count()
          .then(count => {
              if(count > 0) {
                resolve(count);
              } else {
                reject('Something went wrong...');
              }
          });
    }        
}
```

Comment: I wolud like to use variable count in other method so I have to return it.

Comment: Made some updates to my answer. See if that gets you on the right track.

Comment: 'let count = await page.countElements();' it's work. thank man!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help! Do you mind accepting this answer? Thanks.